# Check if Windows imaging components is installed (wic registry)

Tags: windows

How to check whether windows imaging component is installed or not on 64 bit XP machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows imaging component gets installed along with the MSOFFICE.
if not check in registry >>

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Imaging Component
```

Check for InstalledVersion in that regdirectory.

If that key is present then windows imaging component is installed else not

Answer (score 11):

Check the existence of `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll`

Answer (score 2):

Check : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsCodecs.dll

If Windows Imaging Component (WIC) not Installed then
Install Windows Imaging Component before installing SSR 2013 on Windows 2003 or XP system.

32-bit: www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=32

64-bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1385

Answer (score 1):

I found the registry located at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WIC
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to create instance by:

```
CComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> pImagingFactory;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                              IID_IWICImagingFactory, (void**)&pImagingFactory);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pImagingFactory != NULL)
{
    pImagingFactory.Release();
    pImagingFactory = NULL;
    return false;
}
```