# Windows Imaging Component on Windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wic

I am having trouble displaying pictures in my web application.
Someone asked me to check if Windows Imaging Component was registered.

It cannot be found at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Imaging Component

But I read [Check if Windows imaging components is installed (wic registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553764/check-if-windows-imaging-components-is-installed-wic-registry) and it is registered at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\WIC

[image]

Is it well installed ?
Thanks

Comment: WIC is built into Windows Server 2008 R2.